# How To Start CS:GO again?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

i just wanted to ask you guys how can a make a fresh start on CS:GO ? or transform my items to a new steam account without buying games on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this for free.

To do this you will have to have another account with either CSGO bought again or have another account that has family sharing enabled.

To use Family Sharing you have to buy any game on your new account and enable Steam Guard.  Then you can share all your games with your second account for no cost and also have friends and trade.

Comment: Thanks ! realy ok so buy a cheap game then use the family share thank you man !!! :)))